# Jquery mobile form data submit between two pages in a single file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

> I want send the data 'home_page' page to 'get_data' page.how to get the
>   data from home page and send to the second page using jquery

```
<div class="main">
<!-- first page -->
    <section id="home_page" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </header><!-- /header -->
        <article role="main" class="ui-content">
        <!-- Form -->
            <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
             form data send here            
            </form>
        </article><!-- /content -->
        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </footer><!-- /footer -->
    </section><!-- second page -->
    <section id="get_data" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </header><!-- /header -->
        <article role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p> display the data here from home page </p>
        </article><!-- /content -->
        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </footer><!-- /footer -->
    </section><!-- /page -->
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify are you using Multi page template or are your pages different HTML pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  grab the form data on page 1 and append the form values to the 2nd page. when that's done you can then change the page if you wish. In the demo, the Submit button goes to the 2nd page.

**code**

```
$("#sub").on( "click", function( event ) {
var first = $('#first').val();
var last  = $('#last').val();

$("#formdata").empty();

var pagedata = $("<p>" + first + "</p><p>" + last + "</p>");    

pagedata.appendTo("#formdata");

$("#formdata").enhanceWithin();

$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#get_data", { transition: "pop" } );    
})
```

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/j6btvLym/

Comment: Please understand this is two pages I want to transfer the data between two page.the section id "home_page" is one page and the id "get_data" is another one page.your answer is working for a single page.

Comment: probably didnt understand the answer clearly -- here, i made a demo for you. fill in the form and press submit -- http://jsfiddle.net/j6btvLym/

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear friend...this i expect from you...jesus bless you